# Solution to accidental multiple enteries of form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have the jquery/ajax:

```
$('form').bind('submit', function () {
     $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: "Write-to.php",
         data: $("form").serialize(),
         success: function () {
             $.get("Data.php", function (data1) {
                 console.log(data1);
                 $(".data").html(data1);
                 scrolltobottom();
                 setFocusToTextBox();
                 $("#usermsg").val("");
             });
             $('.submited').show();
             $('.submited').html("S E N T");
             $("#usermsg").val("");

             setTimeout(function () {
                 $('.submited').fadeOut(1000);
             }, 2000);
         }
     });

     return false;
 });
```

But with this when I click enter I still have to wait for a bit before the `$("#usermsg").val("");` which leads to accidental double enters because the user thinks they haven't sent the form when they actually have.

*I have set up in the php, a function that does not allow any empty forms.*

#### What can I do to prevent multiple entries?

Comment: You can modify the UI on click to indicate the form has been submitted. Then you could revert on error, or proceed on success. An example might be: On click, disable the submit button. On error, re-enable the button. On success, do your default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unbind the on submit after the form is submitted and bind another function with just `return false;` which prevents the form to be submitted again.

```
var submitting = 0;
$('form').bind('submit', function () {
     if(!submitting)
     {
         submitting = 1;
         $.ajax({
             type: 'post',
             url: "Write-to.php",
             data: $("form").serialize(),
             success: function () {
                submitting = 0;
                $.get("Data.php", function (data1) {
                     console.log(data1);
                     $(".data").html(data1);
                     scrolltobottom();
                     setFocusToTextBox();
                     $("#usermsg").val("");
                });
                $('.submited').show();
                $('.submited').html("S E N T");
                $("#usermsg").val("");

                setTimeout(function () {
                   $('.submited').fadeOut(1000);
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
     }
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: this just blocks me from submitting twice. Full stop!!

Comment: accept/upvote if this solution works and answers your question.

Comment: it doesn't that is why I have taken it away!

Comment: i don't understand. you want to prevent the second submit but you are taking it away because it blocks you to submit twice? it just does what you ask for.

Comment: oh sorry! Entirely my fault I meant prevent until "success"

Comment: Thank you very much sorry about that. Down vote me away!